# Prove whether or not the following is an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, inner-products

> On $P_2$ define $\langle p(x),q(x)\rangle  = p(1)q(1) + p(2)q(2)$ for
>   $p(x),q(x)$ in $P_2$.
>
> I am very confused regarding how to tell that this is an inner
>   product.

I know that in order to show its an inner product the following must hold true:

1) Symmetry:  $\langle f, g \rangle = \langle g, f \rangle$

2) Linearity: $\langle \alpha f,g\rangle = \alpha \langle f,g\rangle$

3) Positive-definite: $\langle f, f \rangle \geq 0$.

I have no idea how to prove it. How do I prove this is or is not an inner product?

Comment: [Here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) the preferred format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symmetry: Let $f, g \in \mathcal{P}2$ then
$$\langle f,g \rangle = f(1)g(1) + f(2)g(2) = g(1)f(1) + g(2)f(2) = \langle g,f \rangle.$$

Linearity: Let $f,g \in \mathcal{P}2$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ then
$$\langle \alpha f,g \rangle = \alpha f(1) g(2) + \alpha f(2) g(2) = \alpha (f(1)g(1) + f(2)g(2)) = \alpha \langle f,g \rangle.$$

Semi positive-definite: Let $f \in \mathcal{P}2$ then 
$$\langle f,f \rangle = f(1)^2 + f(2)^2 \geq 0.$$ It is not positive-definite because the polynomial $f=(X-1)(X-2)$ is nonzero, has degree $2$ but $\langle f,f \rangle =0$. Positive definite means that for all $0 \neq f \in \mathcal{P}2$ we have $\langle f,f \rangle = 0$ and $\langle 0,0 \rangle=0$. So what you're describing is not a inner-product.

You can also show that for any $f,g,h \in \mathcal{P}2$
$$\langle f+g,h \rangle = \langle f,h \rangle + \langle g,h \rangle$$
which shows that this is a semi-inner-product.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. How would it differ if instead of just <p(x),q(x)> = p(1)q(1) + p(2)q(2), it was p(1)q(1) + p(2)q(2) + p(3)q(3). Would that still make it not an inner product?

Comment: @Aeryes It would be an inner product. You can check that all of the properties above still hold and additionally it is also positive definite because if $\langle p,p \rangle = 0$ for some polynomial $p$ of degree $2$ then it has $1,2$ and $3$ as zeros. A degree $2$ polynomial can only have $3$ zeros if it is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show the symmetry of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. Take $f, g$ from $P_2$ and note that

\begin{align}
\langle f(x), g(x) \rangle &= f(1) g(1) + f(2) g(2) \\
&= g(1) f(1) + g(2) f(2) \\
&= \langle g(x), f(x) \rangle.
\end{align}
Here,  $f(1)g(1) = g(1) f(1)$ and $f(2)g(2) = g(2) f(2)$ is true since $f(1) \dots$ are real numbers. Therefore, we have proved symmetry.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I always have found proofs very hard. This class is honestly the first time I feel like I have been exposed to having to prove things.

Comment: Thank you for helping me edit my question to make it more presentable !

Comment: You're welcome.